# GA PagePath Regexp

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm using GBQ to define pagepath data from GA via REGEXP_CONTAINS with no luck.

the code I use is :

```
CASE 
  when REGEXP_CONTAINS(h.page.pagePath, r'\/job\-apply.*\/ref\/.*success=true|cv\-submit\- 
  success|work\-for\-us\/apply\-now\/thank\-you\?') then "Cand Forms"
 ELSE 
 "Other" 
 END AS FormsType
```

this returns all values as 'Others', which is wrong.

I'd be grateful for any help that can resolve the issue.

Many thanks

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because its not programming related may be better suited for https://webapps.stackexchange.com/